# How can I swap between tables with a next and previous button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have this table of t-shirt designs:

```css
#mainProduct {
    
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.card-container {
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#table1 {margin-left: 15px;}
#description {text-align:center; margin-top: 25%; font-size: 12px;}
```

```html
<table id="table1" ;="" cellspacing="25" ;="" text-align="center">

<!--T-REX COFFEE-->
<tr>
 <td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366446">
   <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/BrcRPOF9yezzdQA7qI0GGt9CQpA=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/0cc5/th/pre/i/2016/059/a/a/1_t_rex_coffee_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfftx.png">
     </div>
    <div class="side back">
     <p id="description">What better way to show you love coffee than with a prehistoric predator!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</a>
</td>

<!--TAFFY CAT BATUSI-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366550">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/_WQLrq--RN0K8ixtplOOzyahVko=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre14/aefe/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/7/14_taffycat_batusi_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg15.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">What's better than Taffy Cat doing the Batusi? Taffy cat doing the Batusi on a t-shirt!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

<!--SMILEY CONVERSE-->

<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/kxTUWMz6TsfYVFSd_YSycsGW70I=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/bbd1/th/pre/i/2016/059/8/f/36_smiley_red_shoe_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg7p.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Smiley red shoe. Because ... shoe!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<!--I'M BUFF-->

<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/UCKBK6KyJzceGbuB8szw-ucEZ2Y=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/a544/th/pre/i/2016/059/e/9/18_buff_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfq5g.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Curvy-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/Lljv-RDFIKZCRuTf-GAxc0_BI0o=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/da78/th/pre/i/2016/059/7/c/19_curvy_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfqau.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Love female&female-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t01.deviantart.net/hGoyHjNSwG-HMyz4tBPYyWBJnD8=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/bc6e/th/pre/i/2016/059/c/8/42_love3_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo91.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<!--love male&male-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t04.deviantart.net/cgbfKcYI8e56QSdswTVHPMG8LOI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre12/3e14/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/b/41_love2_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo4w.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--420 Deadpool-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/yUSAlWXmNVP8S_eBilkJrQVe3h0=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/9557/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/d/26_420pool_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfltp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Super Taffy Cat-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/_ynkAcDVU3UrjIgmeUhz49Itxzs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre10/c388/th/pre/i/2016/059/5/c/15_taffycat14_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfmhe.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<!--Taffy Cat book-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Prop of 420-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--All that list-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Now I'd like to have next and previous buttons that when clicked switch to another table like this in the same exact spot. So for example some one would see this table then they click the next button and a new table of t-shirt designs is shown. Any ideas?

Comment: "Here's my layout; make it interactive!" - doesn't work like that. Try it yourself first, then come back with specific questions. As a suggestion, check out http://www.datatables.net. Also, you can't have two HTML elements with the same `id`. Good luck.

Comment: That was my problem I wasn't sure what to look for. Thanks for pointing me in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to control the `display` style by JavaScript. Change to **empty string** when the page should display and change to `none` when the page should hide.

The following example add page css class to each `tr` to defined which row belongs to which page.

```js
var pages = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3'];
var currPageIdx = 0;


function updatePageInd() {
  console.log("Update Page: " + (currPageIdx + 1));
  document.getElementById("pageInd").innerHTML = (currPageIdx + 1) + '/' + pages.length;
}

function setClassVisbility(className, visable) {
  console.log("Set " + className + " Visability to " + visable);
  var doms = [];
  doms = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  console.log(doms);
  if (!!doms && doms.length > 0) {
    var display = !visable ? "none" : "";
    console.log(className + ": " + display);
    for (var i = 0; i < doms.length; i++) {
      var dom = doms[i];
      console.log(dom);
      dom.style.display = display;
    }
  }

}

function nextPage() {
  if (currPageIdx >= pages.length - 1) return;
  setClassVisbility(pages[currPageIdx], false);

  currPageIdx++;

  setClassVisbility(pages[currPageIdx], true);

  updatePageInd();
}

function prevPage() {
  if (currPageIdx <= 0) return;
  setClassVisbility(pages[currPageIdx], false);

  currPageIdx--;

  setClassVisbility(pages[currPageIdx], true);

  updatePageInd();
}

function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    if (i != currPageIdx) {
      setClassVisbility(pages[i], false);
    } else {
      setClassVisbility(pages[i], true);
    }

  }

  updatePageInd();
}

document.getElementById("prevBtn").addEventListener("click", prevPage);
document.getElementById("nextBtn").addEventListener("click", nextPage);
window.addEventListener('load', init, false)
```

```css
#mainProduct {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.card-container {
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#table1 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#description {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<button id="prevBtn">Previous</button> <span id="pageInd">1 / 1</span> 
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

<table id="table1" ;="" cellspacing="25" ;="" text-align="center">

  <!--T-REX COFFEE-->
  <tr class="page1">
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366446">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/BrcRPOF9yezzdQA7qI0GGt9CQpA=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/0cc5/th/pre/i/2016/059/a/a/1_t_rex_coffee_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfftx.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description">What better way to show you love coffee than with a prehistoric predator!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>

    <!--TAFFY CAT BATUSI-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366550">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/_WQLrq--RN0K8ixtplOOzyahVko=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre14/aefe/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/7/14_taffycat_batusi_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg15.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description">What's better than Taffy Cat doing the Batusi? Taffy cat doing the Batusi on a t-shirt!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>

    <!--SMILEY CONVERSE-->

    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/kxTUWMz6TsfYVFSd_YSycsGW70I=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/bbd1/th/pre/i/2016/059/8/f/36_smiley_red_shoe_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg7p.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description">Smiley red shoe. Because ... shoe!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="page1">

    <!--I'M BUFF-->

    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/UCKBK6KyJzceGbuB8szw-ucEZ2Y=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/a544/th/pre/i/2016/059/e/9/18_buff_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfq5g.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <!--Curvy-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/Lljv-RDFIKZCRuTf-GAxc0_BI0o=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/da78/th/pre/i/2016/059/7/c/19_curvy_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfqau.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <!--Love female&female-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t01.deviantart.net/hGoyHjNSwG-HMyz4tBPYyWBJnD8=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/bc6e/th/pre/i/2016/059/c/8/42_love3_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo91.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="page1">
    <!--love male&male-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t04.deviantart.net/cgbfKcYI8e56QSdswTVHPMG8LOI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre12/3e14/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/b/41_love2_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo4w.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <!--420 Deadpool-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/yUSAlWXmNVP8S_eBilkJrQVe3h0=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/9557/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/d/26_420pool_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfltp.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <!--Super Taffy Cat-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/_ynkAcDVU3UrjIgmeUhz49Itxzs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre10/c388/th/pre/i/2016/059/5/c/15_taffycat14_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfmhe.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="page1">
    <!--Taffy Cat book-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <!--Prop of 420-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <!--All that list-->
    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">
              <img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="page2">

    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">This is Page 2
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="page3">

    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">This is Page 3 First Row
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="page3">

    <td id="mainProduct">
      <a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side">This is Page 3 Second Row
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
              <p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>

  </tr>



</table>
```